# How to scale some text based on the size of its container?

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview that i would like to scale as the container grows.  i need to maintain the aspect ratio of it as the container gets bigger. how can this be done ?

usually we give a textview size in sp but for this i want the textview to be proportioned based on the size of its container. In constraintLayout i do the following:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/glStart"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/glEnd"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
tools:text="My textview" />
```

which constraints the textview but it does not constraint the text itself:

[image]

how can i get the text to be constrained to the top and bottom of the container instead of my sp value ?

Answer (score 1):

Add those attributes to your TextView in your layout

```
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="50sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Different phones got different screen size and density, so when you are giving your view text size in sp it will not be responsive and adjust according to the container size.

---

I think that you can use [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) library and keep your constraints as is.

> An android lib that provides a new size unit - ssp (scalable sp). This size unit scales with the screen size based on the sp size unit (for texts). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

From the docs:

**dependencies**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

**How to use**

Simply add to your textView your wanted dimensions (but in ssp) and it will scale up/down according to your container

```
android:textSize="@dimen/_40ssp"
```

---

Another simple option would be to use [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)